# Изучение oracle 12c

Tags: oracle

Посоветуйте пожалуйста книгу по oracle 12c. Начиная с нуля. Т.е. где расписано что вообще такое оракл с чем его едят.. как установить и т.д. документацию не предлагайте пожалуйста. Хотел бы книгу где по простому расписано с примерами.

Answer (score 2):

1. Том Кайт. Oracle для профессионалов.
2. Санжей Мишра, Алан Бьюли. Секреты Oracle SQL.
3. Урман Скотт. Oracle9/ PL/SQL Programming.